# How to remove commas in the middle of a specific line in a file in linux/unix

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

Someone was trying to be helpful in their test description.  However, they added commas to the description so that when the test description is outputted to the log file, the results have extra commas.  This makes it difficult to parse the results since the number of commas vary in the results file.

I want to use sed and go into the test files to remove the commas from the description so we don't get bitten in the butt anymore, but I'm not sure what the regex should look like since I need to preserve everything else and remove just the commas.  The line is from a jmeter jmx file.

Here are a few sample lines:

1 comma

```
HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="avgRespTime inst = green, 12 hr" enabled="true">
```

2 commas

```
HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="avgRespTime, inst = network, 2 days" enabled="true">
```

Can someone give me a hint on how to search for this line and remove only commas while keeping everything else intact?  Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

EDIT:  There might be other lines in the jmx file that contain a comma too so I can't blindly say something like:

```
sed -i 's/,//g' file.jmx
```

Comment: So do you want all commas from the file removed?  If not please provide more information on which ones should be removed, for example from all lines starting with "HTTPSamplerProxy", or all lines within a testname attribute, etc.

Comment: @F.J, thx for the quick reply.  There might be other lines with commas in the jmx file but I don't want to touch those.  I just want to remove all commas from lines that look like the lines in my question; with the HTTPSampleProxy.

Comment: I am not familiar with JMX but it looks like XML, you could possibly use XSLT or even write a quick script in python to parse in the XML, do the regex and write it back out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tr to remove all commas from a given string:

```
s='HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="avgRespTime, inst = network, 2 days" enabled="true">'
tr -d <<< "$s"
```

Or to change it inline using sed in all the lines that have `HTTPSamplerProxy` text :

```
sed -i.bak '/HTTPSamplerProxy/s/,//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '/HTTPSamplerProxy/ {gsub(/,/,"")} 1' file
```

It will search for line with `HTTPSamplerProxy`, then replace `,` with nothing
After this is done the `1` will than print everything out.

If you like to write back data to the original file like the `sed -i 'code'` do:

```
awk '/HTTPSamplerProxy/ {gsub(/,/,"")} 1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```